# VECM terms of variables

Tags: time-series, econometrics, logarithm, vector-error-correction-model, eviews

I have estimated a VECM model of 4 endogenous variables and 3 exogenous, before solving my model, I would like to introduce another variable (endog, let's say (X)) which is calculated with a formula containing two of my endogenous variables (by adding its formula to the VECM).Note that all my endogenous variables in the VECM are expressed in natural logarithm ('log' in eviews notation).
My question is about if I need to express the endogenous variables in my formula [x= endog1 - (endog2*a+b)/d] in 'log' too, so my model can be correct, or should let the formula as it is?, taking in consideration that (a),(b) and (d) cannot be expressed in log.
thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a subject-matter consideration than a statistical one. As long as the model's assumptions are satisfied, you can input variables in levels, logs or other transformations. The more interesting question may be the economic interpretation. Given the transformation you are considering, which one makes sense economically? To answer that, we do not need statistical expertise but require the subject-matter one.